# Usage of bootstrap 4 or ng-bootstrap components in angular 4

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

We are evaluating whether to use bootstrap 4 directly in angular 4 app by importing their styles and java scripts or to use ng-bootstrap angular components for better performance and better interoperability with angular app.
Please share your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)**  contains a set of native Angular directives based on Bootstrap’s markup and CSS. As a result, it's not dependent on `jQuery or Bootstrap’s` JavaScript

**NOTE**
`ng-bootstrap` requires Bootstrap's 4 css to be added to your project and you need to Install it explicitly

Where bootstrap 4 is dependent on `jQuery` and `Bootstrap’s JavaScript`.
I would suggest you to go for `ng-bootstrap` because it would hugely impact  final bundle size

Comment: ng-bootstrap does not support angular 4 right? https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started